# Server too Busy - IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, asp

After a month of looking into this, googling, and trying different "solutions" it has me stumped. We have a server with plenty of hardware to support the number of sites we are running on it, however, we consistently run into the "Server too Busy" error message.

This message normally last 30 seconds to a minute, and then the site functions as if nothing has happened. I can never force this to occur, no matter how many requests I fire at any of the sites on the server, it never will happen.

My question really boils down to what could cause this, and how can I correct it.

Comment: I'm assuming you've gone through all the [optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050(v=bts.10).aspx) settings recommended by Microsoft? Do the logs say anything? Does it happen at a particular time of day?

Comment: Yeah, we have went through everything that has been recommended by Microsoft, and we have not seen anything in the logs that sticks out. Also no, not a particular time of day, it happens all through-out the day, on and off for every site on the server.

Comment: Is this server IIS only? Is Exchange, SQL, or any 3rd party apps running? How many app pools are being used?

Comment: It is only running IIS, yes, and approx. 350 app pools

Comment: did you get any solution modifying web.config configuration ?